# Rails can't see table edges

Tags: html, html-table, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to make a table for my model and I dont like its appearance. The examples on internet look normal, but mine have a visual problem. My index.html.erb is

```
<table class="pretty">  
  <tr>  
    <th><%= sortable "name" %></th>
    <th><%= sortable "city" %></th>
    <th><%= sortable "country" %></th>
    <th><%= sortable "street_address" %></th>
    <th><%= sortable "sector" %></th>
    <th><%= sortable "telephone" %></th>
    <th><%= sortable "fax" %></th>
  </tr>  

  <% for company in @companies %>  
  <tr>  
    <td><%= company.name %></td>
    <td><%= company.city %></td>
    <td><%= company.country %></td>
    <td><%= company.street_address %></td>
    <td><%= company.sector %></td>
    <td><%= company.telephone %></td>
    <td><%= company.fax %></td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

It should look like this:

[image]

Mine looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this in some basic way. I changed the table row into this:

```
<table class="pretty" border="1" cellpadding="10">
```